# How to get value from collection angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, collections, directive

I'm new in AngularJs and I don't know how to get single value from collection AngularJs. I have a list of Integer and my code is as follows:>

```html
<div ng-controller="ChartCtrl1">
      {{ orderDateList1 }}
</div>
```

And controller code:

```
var ChartCtrl1 = function ($scope, OrderDate) {
    $scope.orderDateList1 = OrderDate.get({
        action: 'orderDate',
        locationId: location.hash.substring(1),
        month: 10,
        year: 2014
    });
};
```

And View like this:

```
{"collection":[10,14]}
```

But I want to compare every single result (number in this case) to some other method for example. I think best view will be: 10,14. Suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What would be the desired outcome? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do here. Maybe you are looking to filter your results before displaying them?

Comment: Maybe it will be good to get a filter, i dont have to many experience in angularJs. In short: my list returns integer value and i want to compare every single value in my other method but now when i even display return of my list it show me like this: {"collection":[10,14]}. I cant compare "that string" to my other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a filter, I suppose:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    {{ list | map:'collection' }}
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/gbydrLmc/)

I included a filter example for jQuery's map, _.underscore's map, and two filter libraries on GitHub that have these filters built in.

```
/*
[10,14,2,5] (custom jQuery map filter)
[[10,14],[2,5]] (custom Underscore map filter)
[[10,14],[2,5]] (angular-filters by a8m)
[[10,14],[2,5]] (angular-filters by frapontillo)
*/
```

Comment: use `collection | map: 'collection' | flatten` to get the same result as jquery